# Creating a histogram from iterations of a binomial distribution in R

Tags: r

Here are the instructions:
Create 10,000 iterations (N = 10,000) of
rbinom(50,1, 0.5) with n = 50 and your guess of p0 = 0.50 (hint: you will need to
construct a for loop). Plot a histogram of the results of the sample. Then plot your
pstar on the histogram. If  pstar is not in the extreme region of the histogram, you would
assume your guess is correct and vice versa. Finally calculate the probability that
p0 < pstar (this is a p value).

I know how to create the for loop and the rbinom function, but am unsure on how transfer this information to plotting on a histogram, in addition to plotting a custom point (my guess value).

Comment: Sounds like homework. Can you show how far you have gotten? What's pstar?

Comment: > for (i in 1:10000)                       + rbinom(50,1,0.5)

Comment: I have the for loop created, and have ran rbinom. I want to know how I can properly store these iterations and plot a histogram from this data. I know the default functions for each.

Comment: Ok, first off, that's not proper R code. Did you even look at my answer below, where I show that you don't need a foor loop. I'm unsure at the moment where the problem lies. You might want to grab an intro R book to learn some R basics first, if you're not clear on how to generate/store/plot R objects. You also didn't answer my question concerning pstar. I suggest editing your question to include whatever working R code you have to show how far you have gotten on your own. Then we can take it from there.

Comment: sounds good, I'll edit the question, still trying to remind myself how to embed code. I understand that I don't need a for loop, but I believe that I'm limited to using the for loop, as the focus on the concepts I need to learn is the statistical aspect of this. So each time rbinom runs, I'm trying to find the number of 1s out of the total 0s and 1s. pstar is the fraction of 1s in the total number of generated values. This is performed 10,000 times, which is plotted on the histogram to see what proportions are most popular. I must guess if 0.5 is a reasonable guess my analyzing the histogram.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to generate samples using an explicit for loop. Please take a look. Also, as I expected in my answer below, `pstar` is the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) for parameter p (i.e. the probability of success for every trial), based on your sample data. You should take a look again at my complete answer below to see how to e.g. inspect the distribution of estimated pstar values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not doing your homework for you, but this should get you started. You don't say what pstar is supposed to be, so I am assuming you are interested in the (distribution of the) maximum likelihood estimates for p.

You create 10,000 `N=50` binomial samples (there is no need for a `for` loop):

```
sample <- lapply(seq(10^5), function(x) rbinom(50, 1, 0.5))
```

The ML estimates for `p` are then

```
phat <- sapply(sample, function(x) sum(x == 1) / length(x))
```

Inspect the distribution

```
require(ggplot)
ggplot(data.frame(phat = phat), aes(phat)) + geom_histogram(bins = 30)
```

and calculate the probability that `p0 < phat`.

---

**Edit 1**
If you *insist*, you can also use a for loop to generate your samples.

```
sample <- list();
for (i in 1:10^5) {
    sample[[i]] <- rbinom(50, 1, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. I'll be adding my code as soon as I figure out how to embed it.

Comment: Great. Good luck with your assignment.